# The connection between Brun's constant and Dusart's bounds

Tags: limits, number-theory, prime-numbers

Brun's constant $B$ is defined as the sum of the reciprocals of twin primes, that is, prime numbers that differ by $2$:

$$B = \sum_{p,p+2 \in P} \Big(\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p+2}\Big)$$

where $P$ is the set of all twin prime pairs.

Dusart's bounds, found in 1999, are a series of inequalities that give upper and lower bounds for the $n^{th}$ prime number $p_n$. One of Dusart's most precise bounds is the following:

$$p_n < n(\log n + \log \log n - 0.9385)$$

Using Dusart's bound for $p_n$, it is possible to derive an upper bound for Brun's constant $B$ in terms of $p_n$. In particular, we have:

$$B < 2 + \frac{2}{3\log \log p_n}$$

This formula provides an upper bound on the value of Brun's constant as a function of $p_n$, using Dusart's bounds for the $n^{th}$ prime. While this bound is not very tight, it does show that Brun's constant grows relatively slowly compared to the $n^{th}$ prime, and gives an indication of how the size of $B$ is related to the distribution of twin primes.

My question is: if $B$ constant grows relatively slowly, it is well known that $B$ converges. Where is my mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm skeptical of the specific inequality $B<2+\frac23\frac1{\log\log p_n}$; when $n$ is large that would be better than anything known in the literature. Even granting that inequality, however, I don't understand your question: what made you think there's a mistake? That inequality is certainly consistent with the sum defining $B$ converging.

Comment: You should be careful with your notation. "$p,p+2 \in P$" is usually read as "$p$ and $p+2$ are in $P$". That's not the sum defining Brun constant.

Comment: "While this bound is not very tight, it does show that Brun's constant grows relatively slowly compared to the $n$th  prime" A constant cannot grow. I do not see the purpose of your bound. Naturally, one likes to have a bound as sharp as possible. So letting $n\to +\infty$ in your bound gives $B\leq 2$.